# Find where a hosts rule is defined on macOS

Tags: networking, osx, dns, firewall, hosts

Is there a way to find out how my system came up with the IP address for a certain domain? On my machine, `ping`ing analytics.google.com returns `127.0.0.1`, and I don't know how it came up with that. my `/private/etc/hosts` file is in default condition.

Is there a way to know how the system came up with that address? E.g. was it from another hosts file, the DNS, or something else?

Comment: Cross-posted on https://superuser.com/questions/1277901/find-where-a-hosts-rule-is-defined-on-macos

Comment: Yeah, I realized here is probably a better place for the question. I'm about to delete the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no, unless you `dtrace` the system to see what is doing what. Without `dtrace` you can *dig* around to try to see which source might be to blame

Is it coming from a DNS server? (also try `@` different public DNS servers to see if there's any local DNS shenanigans going on, such as a local caching nameserver that has a zone for `analytics.google.com`, or maybe some firewall is redirecting packets to a local ns...)

```
$ grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.96.1
$ dig +short @192.168.96.1 analytics.google.com
...
$ dig +short @8.8.8.8 analytics.google.com
...
```

What does the mDNS system think (this probably polls DNS; also run `tcpdump` or WireShark and look for port `53` or port `5353` DNS packets to see what that shows)

```
$ dns-sd -q analytics.google.com
...
^C
```

This will show what the Apple cache has, which may be different from DNS if something in Appleland is different

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name analytics.google.com
...
```

and then there's this to clear anything wonky in the cache...

```
$ dscacheutil -flushcache
```

then see if any of the above `dns-sd` or `dscacheutil -q host` report something different. If the entry is coming from a file, then after clearing the cache run `opensnoop` which is a dtrace script that should show file opens; investigate the contents of these after doing a lookup to see if any have the record in question.